# integer to bytes - conversion problems - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I want to send data via a serial bus to a device. Need to convert integer values to 4 bytes. So far so good.

For most values it works, while for e.g. `100` I get results which I do not understand:

```
(5000).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big') -> b'\x00\x00\x13\x88'
```

that's what I expected from paper, however

```
(100).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big') -> b'\x00\x00\x00d'
```

while I would expect for 100 the 4 bytes `b'\x00\x00\x00\x64'`

Why the difference?

How to fix the length to -exactly- a 4 byte representation?

Answer (score 2):

In python, the `d` and `P` values in bytestrings are bytes that represent ASCII characters, where the `d` replaces `64` and `P` replaces `50`. This is the way python does I guess.

Now, let us see with example:

```
int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x00d', byteorder='big')
#output
100

int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x00\x00\x64', byteorder='big')
#output
100
```

You can also check with `bytes.hex()`

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x64'.hex()
#output
'00000064'


b'\x00\x00\x00d'.hex()
#output
'00000064'
```

Comment: Thank you! The different representation was totally new to me. Do you know of any way to keep the "normal" notation?

Comment: Sorry I do not know, maybe someone will answer after seeing this question.

Comment: You can pass a space to make it slightly easier to read, i.e. `b'\x00\x00\x00\x64'.hex(' ')` which gives `00 00 00 64`